# How could I turn this into a thread so it doesn't freeze up my app?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

So I was wanting to know how I would go about turning this into a thread? I have tried and failed multiple times. I am about read to give up and just deal with the application freezing while it gets a response.

```
package me.robert.tb.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class HTTPConnect {

private static BufferedReader reader = null;
private static StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

/**
 * This method is used to connect to a website and return its response.
 * Mainly used for connecting to API's
 *
 * @param link
 *            The URL of the website
 * @return The response from the website
 */
public static String getResponse(String link) {
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new      URL(link).openStream()));

    int read;
    char[] chars = new char[1024];
    while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
    buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
} catch (Exception e) {
} finally {
    try {
    if (reader != null)
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
return buffer.toString();
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also just as a side note, I have also tried to use Callables but my app still seems to freeze up even when using those.... I might have been trying to implement them wrong, I don't know.

Comment: Okay, instead of turning that into a thread I am just creating a method that creates a thread and sets the variables I want set with the JsonObject it creates.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  Though you shouldn't really need threads to import 1024 characters.  On a few test pages it ran pretty quickly.  I think your main issue is trying to make `getResponse()` static. Anyway, here's your modified code using a thread.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class HTTPConnect implements Runnable{

    private static BufferedReader reader = null;
    private static StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    private String link;
    private String response;

    /**
     * This method is used to connect to a website and return its response.
     * Mainly used for connecting to API's
     *
     * @param link
     *            The URL of the website
     * @return The response from the website
     */
    public HTTPConnect(String input){
        link = input;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(link).openStream()));

            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
                response = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public String getResponse(){
        return response;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        String website = "http://google.com";
        Thread t = new Thread(new HTTPConnect(website));
        t.run();
    }
}
```